# Read Request Payload in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, http-headers

Trying out Content Security Policy and using the Report Only method and the data is sending a POST (See edits, supposed to be POST, but Request Headers say GET) to my page which I then use to email myself. In the browser developer tools I can see the data in the Request Payload, but I don't know how to access this scope. The `FORM` scope is empty and the `GetHttpRequestData()` doesn't show a `Payload` key.

How do I access the data in the Request Payload in ColdFusion?

**EDIT:** In the dev tools I can see in the network tab a POST to the page with 4 sections: `General`, `Response Headers`, `Request Headers` and `Request Payload`. I need to access the `Request Payload` data.

**Request Headers:**

```
GET /campuses/content-report/ HTTP/1.1
Host: domain.com
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Referer: http://domain.com/page/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: **[Removed]**
```

**Request Payload:**

```
{
   "csp-report":{
      "document-uri":"http://domain.com/page/",
      "referrer":"http://domain.com/",
      "violated-directive":"default-src 'self' 'sha256-L2Tc50iUaBz2udc-dnkwO-FKzrsl5cLnzkFu5LgX5ao=' https://stats.g.doubleclick.net http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com http://www.google-analytics.com https://www.google.com https://fonts.gstatic.com https://ajax.googleapis.com https://cdn.jsdelivr.net https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com http://www.etutoring.org",
      "effective-directive":"img-src",
      "original-policy":"default-src 'self' 'sha256-L2Tc50iUaBz2udc-dnkwO-FKzrsl5cLnzkFu5LgX5ao=' https://stats.g.doubleclick.net http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com http://www.google-analytics.com https://www.google.com https://fonts.gstatic.com https://ajax.googleapis.com https://cdn.jsdelivr.net https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com;script-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com https://ajax.googleapis.com https://cdn.jsdelivr.net 'nonce-3E89EBDB49F712C7D90D1B39E348BBBF';report-uri /campuses/content-report;",
      "blocked-uri":"https://www.google-analytics.com",
      "status-code":200
   }
}
```

`GetHttpRequestData` contains Request Headers but not Request Payload. I did notice that the website I read said the Security policy would send the data via POST but the Headers say GET. Would that cause the issue? Should they be in the `URL` scope? Not at my machine at the moment.

Comment: How are you sending the data? (please provide code or headers+body from devtools)

Comment: Content Security Policy sends it itself. I don't do it manually. I can see the request in the network tab in the browser developer tools. I can see for example Request Headers and then there is a Request Payload and I can see the data the Content Security Policy is sending there in JSON format. I'm guessing it's the Browser that triggers the POST request.

Comment: And, how exactly are you trying to get the data? `GetHttpRequestData` is the correct method. I'm guessing your usage is incorrect. (note that if you would have simply provided relevant code in your question, you would likely already have an answer.)

Comment: I can show you the output of `GetHttpRequestData` but the data in the Request Payload from the browser dev tools is not found in the struct returned from `GetHttpRequestData`. The function currently returns everything in the Request Headers as referenced in my post edit.

Comment: it should have a `content` key.

Comment: The content is empty.

Comment: does the post request have a proper content type?

Comment: cmon just post the code and headers, i'm tired of playing 90 questions.

Comment: How do I copy the headers from dev tools in browser?

Comment: In chrome you can select them just like any other text using your mouse. If all else fails, a screen capture of that portion will work too.

Comment: Right but the content is empty when I dump the response of `GetHttpRequestData()`

Comment: sorry bout last comment, didn't see your edit. investigating.

Comment: It really should be a POST request simply because it contains a request body. Typically GET requests don't contain bodies. I'm not sure how to obtain a request body in coldfusion for a GET request.

Comment: Right, I think his post is right. When I get back I'm going to dump the other scopes. I know `FORM` was empty. If it's nowhere I need to see why it's doing a GET instead of a POST because I can't control that. The Content Policy header just does it itself. It's just strange because I can see it in the dev tool.s

Comment: I'm sure it's possible to retrieve the content in one way or another, even if it means dipping into some Java, but i'd be surprised if there wasn't a built-in way to do it.

Comment: Well if it's not in the `Headers` and not in the `FORM`, there is only one place left no? I didn't mean to not show code, I just figured I was doing something obviously wrong, but it looks like I was doing the right thing, or at least looking in the right spot for a `POST` request. It's just doing a GET.

Comment: I haven't written any coldfusion in almost 2 years, so my coldfusion-foo is a bit rusty

Comment: Wow. It's not in the `URL` scope either. Where the hell is this data?

Comment: you used cfdump on the return from `GetHttpRequestData()` right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82715/discussion-between-kevin-b-and-leeish).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I was looking in the right spot, `GetHttpRequestData` but what I didn't realize was I setup the url to not have a trailing slash and my IIS Rewrite rules was redirecting to the `/` version of the page and the header data was being lost in the process.

Comment: That pretty much explains all the weirdness. :) now i'm curious if coldfusion correctly reads/presents the request body of a GET request, even though GET requests shouldn't have one. my assumption would be it does. don't forget to accept your answer.